# Time Machine with GUI for Linux Mint

Tags: backup, gui

I try to find Time Machine for Linux Mint which has GUI and is easy to use for Linux unexperienced person.

Similar features which Macintosh Time Machine has.

Backups entire boot drive hourly.

Comment: For your files (e.g. source code & configuration files), you probably should consider using some version control system like [git](http://git-scm.com/)

Comment: I've edited the answer to address your specific feature requests.

Answer (score 3):

This question is a little vague, as you do not state what aspects of Time Machine you find important. I use [Back In Time](http://backintime.le-web.org/), which features incremental backups, based on `rsync` and hard-links.

Hence, each additional backup only uses the amount of space for the files that have changed. However, you can easily browse through previous snapshots, either with a normal file browser or the Back In Time GUI.

### EDIT

You can configure it via the GUI to run every x hours too. However, you can probably do this with most backup programs, using `cron`.

Comment: *Oddly* enough, I think the question is extremely specific.  I recently suffered two (x2)  catastrophic hard-drive failures and my MAC-time-machine _using_ colleagues assure me that the mean-time-to-resume-work is measured in HOURS, not days.  To be honest; it is really weeks because I haven't loaded various bit-n-pieces yet that will definitely need later (e.g. an Ada compiler).  The APPLE(tm) TimeMachine thing is such a useful concept; that I'm amazed nothing _similar_ has show-up.  Come-on everyone; how much would it take!  Maybe we need to compare back-in-time with time-machine?

Comment: @will I'm not sure what your complaints are. I've restored complete systems from Back In Time in a matter of minutes. It can be configured to do full disk backups. Better than Time Machine, it's also OS agnostic, so you can just boot into a live CD (or physically connect the internal hard drive to another system), then literally copy from a directory on your backup volume (`last-snapshot`) to your wiped computer. The time to restore is merely the time taken to copy files over.

Answer (score 1):

[Timeshift](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/timeshift) is made for Mint and does exactly what you want.

If you choose the btrfs partition type for "/" during the installation (instead of the default ext4) then you can use this for snapshots of the current state of the system. These snapshots are saved locally.

The used space of a btrfs snapshot is nothing more than the difference between this snapshot and the next snapshot (or the current state of the system if there is no newer snapshot). So snapshots are like incremental backups that are saved locally and are made a lot quicker (takes a couple of seconds).

If Mint is already installed on ext4 it's still possible to convert your partition to btrfs (this is an entirely different topic so i won't elaborate this here)

If you don't want to use btrfs you can still use timeshift as frontend for rsync to save your snapshots externally